# min_width and min_height for the upload class?

Tags: codeigniter

Is there something like min_width and min_height for the upload class?
I found this patch for the upload class:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/143418/#730179

But it isn’t working for me…

Has anyone tried it?

Any other solution out there?

Thanks

Comment: *what* have you tried, post some code please

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working. It was my mistake, a misspelling when changing the upload class. 
The patch works just fine.
Thanks